# Is crystal mandatory on attiny84?

Tags: pwm, attiny, spi

I am trying to make a mini project with attiny84 and I searched the web so I can make an arduino on breadboard. What I saw on the internet is that they didnt use crystal. Is it mandatory if I want to use 1 pwm pin and the SPI interface on the attiny84?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you need crystal accuracy. If the internal RC oscillator is accurate enough then feel free to use it instead.

Comment: Is there any way that i should anable the internal oscillator from the arduino IDE?

Comment: The Arduino IDE has no way to manipulate the fuses without using a programmer. And even with one, you can only modify them to the values set in boards.txt.

Comment: Just to add. The internal oscillator runs at 8mHz, while most arduino boards have a 16mHz crystal. So you lose half the processing speed. In most cases this is not a big deal. On the plus side, it reduces the power usage a bit, and you can use those 2 crystal pins for something else.